# filtering out null values while converting datatable to dictionary using linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, datatable

I am converting a datatable to dictionary using below code:

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(dr => new { Key = dr["key_col"], Value = dr["value_col"] })
    .ToDictionary(kvp => (string)kvp.Key, kvp => (decimal)kvp.Value);
```

but it throws me an 'input string not in correct format' exception. I am pretty sure its because of some `null` rows present in the `datatable`. how can I filter out those null rows from this code?

Comment: The exception cannot be thrown from the code you've shown. Where do you parse the key?

Comment: ok, that exception is not coming anymore. but my new exception is 'specified cast is not valid'. I am actually dumping an excel into datatable where one column is string and another column is decimal. when I am dumping excel into datatable there is no issue. but the moment I try to convert it to a dictionary it gives 'specified cast not valid'.

Comment: are you sure that the datatable contains `decimal` columns and not only string columns? Look at `dt.Columns`. If it only contains strings you can't cast it (or use my `Field<decimal>` approach). You have to parse it, f.e. `decimal.Parse(dr.Field<string>("value_col"))`

Comment: What does `dt.Columns["value_col"].DataType` return?

Comment: you are right @TimSchmelter, the column was in decimal format. however, in the lambda expression when I used `decimal.Parse()` it gave me an error. so I had to use `Convert.ToDecimal(str)` in the end. it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about the exception, but if you want to remove all null-values you can add a [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx)-clause.

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(dr => dr["key_col"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["key_col"].ToString()))
    .Select(dr => new { Key = dr["key_col"], Value = dr["value_col"] })
    .ToDictionary(kvp => (string)kvp.Key, kvp => (decimal)kvp.Value);
```

You may also want to try `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["key_col"] as string)` in the Where-clause. But I've have experienced some problems with it when casting column values. Therefore I tend to use  `dr["key_col"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["key_col"].ToString())` instead.

Comment: i have edited the question and put the exact exception message in the above question. You can check if you want to get some more idea about it. meanwhile, I am trying the solution provided by you.

Comment: ok, that exception is not coming anymore. but my new exception is 'specified cast is not valid'. I am actually dumping an excel into datatable where one column is string and another column is decimal. when I am dumping excel into datatable there is no issue. but the moment I try to convert it to a dictionary it gives 'specified cast not valid'.

Comment: It's probably the cast to decimal. Take a look at the great answer from @Tim Schmelter. Instead of casting you can try to parse the value with double.TryParse

Comment: the column was in decimal format. however, in the lambda expression when I used decimal.Parse() it gave me an error. so I had to use Convert.ToDecimal(str) in the end. it worked.

Answer (score 2):

The only string in the query is the key of the dictionary. The exception suggests that you're trying to convert it to a numeric type later(f.e. `int.Parse`).

You should do this in the query and use a `Dictionary<int, decimal>`. For example:

```
int key;
Dictionary<int, decimal> dict = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(dr => int.TryParse(dr.Field<string>("key_col"), out key))
    .Select(dr => new { Key = key, Value = dr.Field<decimal>("value_col") })
    .ToDictionary(x=> x.Key, x=> x.Value);
```

If it's actually not an `int` but a different type, f.e.`double` use `double.TryParse`